# Utilizando a biblioteca discord.py tem uma forma de salvar o "#ID" do usuário sem ser o "message.author.id"?

Tags: python, biblioteca, discord.py

Eu preciso pegar somente aquele 'id' que vem após o nick do usuário, exemplo: Fulano#1234

Estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != bot.user:
        msg = '~' + message.author.name + '#' + str(message.author.id) + ': ' + message.content
```

Retorno: `~Fulano#987654321456789123: message.content`
Eu gostaria de algo assim: `~Fulano#1234: message.content`
Sendo #1234 o ID que se usa para adicionar a pessoa no discord.

Caso alguém saiba a resposta, tem como me passar a fonte de onde pegou esse objeto do `message.#ID`?

Obrigado ^-^

Answer (score 0):

Consegui

Ao invés de usar `message.author.id` se deve usar `message.author.discriminator`

Assim ele retorna o #ID

Só não achei isso na documentação, tive que pedir ajuda para um amigo =/
Se alguém tiver o link falando sobre esse `message.author.discriminator` na documentação ficarei grato.